# C# DataModel image column returned as byte[0] from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net-entity-data-model

I generated a data model from a SQL Server 2008 Express database and imported a stored procedure as a function import to retrieve rows from a table which it's return value is the generated type for that table.

One of the columns in that table is of `IMAGE` datatype and I was inserting and retrieving these images correctly until it stopped working. Now the `ExecuteFunction<table_generated_class>` is returning the rows requested but the image field is being returned as `byte[0]`.

This is happening in two different computers and I've regenerated the database from scripts but the problem persists, the images get inserted properly (I've checked the field length using `DATALENGTH` and the sizes of the binary contents are consistent with the size of the images I'm inserting) so I'm assuming this isn't a problem in the database or the database server but in the auto-generated code of the data model.

EDIT:

I've created a new project and generated the datamodel again in that project and the images are being retrieved correctly. I went back to the original project, removed the datamodel and re-created a new one and the problem persists. The only difference between one project and the other is that the original project holds the datamodel in a class library.

Does anybody knows what could be going wrong?

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: I've changed the data type to varbinary(MAX) in the database and the problem persists.

Comment: Apparently it was a problem with multithreading. I was openning the database connection in one thread and executing the stored procedure from another. For some reason beyond my understanding, doing this makes the data model fail when retrieving binary data from the database, even when everything gets executed properly without errors or exceptions.